# Зачем писать ключевое слово struct в объявлении указателя?

Tags: c++

```
struct bal {
    float balance;
    char name[80];
} person;

struct bal *p=&person;
```

Зачем писать ключевое слово `struct`? Почему нельзя написать:

```
bal *p=&person;
```

Ведь мы создали и определили отдельный тип `bal`.

Я понимаю, что у меня каша в голове, но разъясните, пожалуйста, как есть.

Comment: Видимо вы путаете С и С++, в С++ это необязательно.

Comment: то есть в с++ можно написать без struct ?

Comment: Использование `struct` дает немного больше определенности читателям вашего кода (впрочем, современные IDE (которые наверняка использует большинство *спрашивающих помощь* на этом сайте) позволяют быстро посмотреть, что это за `bal`)

Comment: В Си нет типа `bal` , но есть структура `struct bal`. В плюсах при определении структуры автоматически создаются тип `bal` **и** структура `struct bal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В большинстве случаев писать `struct` или `class` перед типом определяемой переменной не требуется. В Си явное написание `struct` является необходимым, в C++ можно этим воспользоваться, но обязательного требования нет.

Есть, например, такое исключение. Когда имя класса совпадает с именем функции, то при объявлении объекта нужно указывать ключевое слово `struct` (или `class`):

```
struct F {};

void F() {}

int main() {
    F f;        // ошибка
    struct F f; // ok
}
```

Ещё один вариант, если мы совмещаем предварительное объявление класса с определением переменной:

```
struct F* f1; // т.к. F ещё не объявлен, то нужно добавить struct (или class)
F* f2;        // ошибка

struct F {};  // ниже этого объявления struct уже не является обязательным

F* f3;        // ok
struct F* f4; // тоже ok

int main() { }
```